# Transfer the contents of a file to a collection

Tags: php, laravel

How can I transfer the contents of a file to a collection

File Contents **test.txt**

```
[
    {"nmId":40699165,"price":924,"discount":0,"promoCode":0},
    {"nmId":40384610,"price":4155,"discount":0,"promoCode":0}
]
```

I get it like this

```
$contents = Storage::get('test.txt');
```

I want to get a collection in view at the output

```
[
  ['nmId' => '40699165', 'price' => 924, 'discount' => 0, 'promoCode' => 0],  
  ['nmId' => '40384610', 'price' => 4155, 'discount' => 0, 'promoCode' => 0],  
]
```

Comment: And what's your quesiton about this? What have you tried to achieve that output? Where are you stuck?

Comment: When you do `Storage::get` the output there is a string (specifically JSON string). So you have to convert that string to a PHP array using `json_decode`. Then if you really want to use Laravel's collection class, after using `json_decode` you can use the `collect` method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#creating-collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the json_decode() function assuming the file is formatted correctly.

```
$contents = json_decode(Storage::get('test.txt'), true);
```

If you want a laravel collection

```
$collection = collect($contents);
```